# Converting WAV file to Txt dataset

Tags: r, dataset, signal-processing, wav

I have a wav file of time-domain signal. I want to convert the signal into a discrete sampling dataset (either txt or csv) to import into R for analysis. Does anyone have any recommendations on how should I do this?
Edit for clarification: I have a wav input and I want a txt output in a list of amplitude over discrete sampling of time

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want `txt` output or `wav` output? These two led to vastly different solutions.

Comment: I mistyped - I wanted a csv or txt output. Not sure why I typed wav

Comment: So you want to get the amplitudes of your time-domain signal then write that into a text file? If so, you'd need to do a Fourier transform `fft()` of your signal then save the coefficients.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm just looking for a software to do that on the computer

Comment: I just searched `fft wav file python` on this site and got a dozen of answers, any of which can make your question duplicate. You can use some other language then `python` too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this file as `wav2fftcoef.py` and set its Permission as executable:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import numpy as np
rate, data = wav.read('myfile.wav') # put this in the same folder as this code
np.savetxt("amplitudes.csv", np.abs(fft(data)))
```

Put your wav file `myfile.wav` in the same folder. Then double click to run.